# How to return a value in case of a getting a Firebase Document wihtout using an Interface?

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, global-variables

I need to return a value in my method that is to be downloaded from Firestore. Global variables are not working as I am aware of its **asynchronous** behavior. I found an Interface however that is **not working** and neither restructuring data flow is helping . **I need to find a method to somehow return the value from this method** as there are a lot of method calls dependent on this method so even passing the values through methods is not working out in my case.

[A method named "Get Name" needs to return a string from Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1JCM.jpg)

Comment: You really shouldn't try to make an asynchronous function into a synchronous one.  If you do that, and you call it on the main thread, it will block your app, and it will possibly crash with an ANR.  If you want to know why all the Firebase APIs are asynchronous, [read this article](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93).

Comment: Thanks.It was helpful